# Маппинг enum в string (EntityFramework) или свой строковый тип

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть сущность:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

К этой сущности надо еще добавить поле "Тип", например:

```
public enum EntityType
{
    TypeOne,
    TypeTwo
}
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public EntityType Type { get; set; }
}
```

В дальнейшем к типу EntityType нужно будет добавить методы расширения (IsOk...).

При этом хочется что бы в БД в атрибуте Type было не интовое значение а строковое. Как можно сделать маппинг в EntityFramework 6, что бы Type как enum, можно было использовать в Linq to Sql запросах ?
Как вариант думал отнаследоваться от string и сделать класс со статичными полями этого типа. Тогда в БД были бы строковые значения, и экстеншены распространялись только на мой тип а не на все строки, но от стринга нельзя наследоваться.

Что делать? как решают такую проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте два свойства, одно строковое и отображаемое на базу, второе - перечислимого типа и не отображаемое на базу.

Одно из свойств сделайте основным, а второе пусть будет вычисляемым.

Comment: в таком случае не удастся использовать свойство типа перечисления в запросах так как оно не будет мапиться в таблицу напрямую, или я неправильно понял ?.

Comment: Хм, да, есть такая проблема...

Answer (score -1):

Интересно, зачем использовать Entity и linq2sql в одном проекте?

попробуйте использовать только одну ORM например Entity, там с перечислениями все отлично, можно использовать как и задумывается. а если на каждое перечисление повесить например атрибут Display, то можно вполне и в дропдаунах юзать.
а если уж совсем невтерпеж, то приведение типов вам в руки, загружая через Linq2Sql приводите типы и будет вам счастье

Comment: под linq to sql запросами скорее всего подразумевались обычные запросы через ef, вида `.Where(e => e.SomeEnumProp == SomeEnum.Val1)` - потому что они не работают при типовом решении (которое привел Pavel Mayorov в соседнем ответе). а совсем не использование двух разных orm

Comment: @PashaPash если вопрос только в этом: **"При этом хочется что бы в БД в атрибуте Type было не интовое значение а строковое."**, то да, обратится по человечески не удасться, делать свой велосипед ради лишних данных в базе ИМХО накладно

Comment: всегда могут быть какие-то внешние факторы. например, желание построить отчеты на основе существующей базы (не через EF, а через какой-то сторонний движок). Для целей саппорта, опять же, строки проще (если кому-то приходится лазить напрямую в базу - гораздо удобнее увидеть там, например, "NotImplemented", чем "23"). Так что строковые данные в базе вполне могут быть совсем не лишними.

Comment: @PashaPash действительно, но для этого заводится в базе словарь Ключь/Значение и в отчетах сводится в нужном виде :) но это опять же мое ИМХО :) не более. фильтровать все-же лучше по интам, а любой енумератор это прежде всего фильтр